# How does process manage to keep running even though it receives SIGHUP despite being invoked with nohup?

Tags: python, nohup

I was testing if commands invoked with `nohup` indeed do not get the SIGHUP signal.

I confirmed that if I log into my CentOS box using PuTTY, run `nohup python foo.py &` where foo.py contains an infinite loop and if I kill PuTTY, the python program still keeps running.

Then I wrote sig.py that handles and logs all the signals it receives into sig.txt.

```
import signal, os

def handler(sig, frame):
    f = open('sig.txt', 'a')
    f.write('signal: ' + str(sig) + '\n')
    f.close()

for i in range(1, 20):
    if i in [9, 19]:
        continue
    print 'Setting signal handler for', i
    signal.signal(i, handler)

f = open('sig.txt', 'w')
f.write('start\n')
f.close()

while True:
    pass
```

Then I run `nohup python sig.py &` in a PuTTY terminal. Then I close the PuTTY terminal.

I open a new PuTTY terminal and check the content of sig.txt and I find this in it.

```
$ cat sig.txt
start
signal: 1
```

So it seems that the running process still receives SIGHUP.

If the running process still receives SIGHUP, how is it that it manages to stay alive when invoked with SIGHUP?

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia `nohup` [ignores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) the SIGHUP whereas `disown` actually [prevents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disown_(Unix)) the signal from being sent. In your python script you go through and set the signal handlers for all signals thus overriding the `nohup` functionality.